# unpackaged.zip getting in the way of pulling from scratch org

Tags: lightning-web-components, commandbutton, lwc-wire-adapter

Hey guys I can't pull from my org because of this zip file[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to go about this I used the unzip command in command line, but that didn;t help.

Answer (score 1):

That file is presumably the detritus of an earlier attempt to perform a Metadata API-style source code retrieval. Just move it outside your `force-app` directory, or delete it if it's not needed.